# Mysql count and Group by date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in mysql like this

```
SELECT COUNT(c_Id), DATE_FORMAT(c_Date,'%Y-%m') FROM tbl_complaintsheet  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c_Date, '%Y%m')
```

Now the result is

```
COUNT(c_Id)  DATE_FORMAT(c_Date,'%Y-%m')  
-----------  -----------------------------
          2  2013-12                      
         48  2014-01                      
         85  2014-02                      
         95  2014-03                      
         93  2014-04                      
         63  2014-05                      
         94  2014-06                      
         57  2014-07                      
         70  2014-08                      
         87  2014-09                      
         83  2014-10                      
        101  2014-11                      
        117  2014-12                      
         86  2015-01                      
        126  2015-02                      
        100  2015-03                      
         92  2015-04                      
         82  2015-05                      
          1  2015-08                      
          8  2015-09
```

How Can I pass parameters to this like, where c_date=2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with extracting the year -

`FROM tbl_complaintsheet WHERE YEAR(c_date)=2014`

Comment: this will not use index, so may be slow if there is huge data in table, so you can use "where c_date like '2014%'" which will use index and will be fast.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Hmm.. But for that the indexes must be set first.

Comment: definitely index should be there as per requirement, but we should write query to keep scope of optimization, due to this i mentioned my remarks in accepted answer...

Answer (score 2):

You may try by aliasing and using like

```
SELECT COUNT(c_Id), DATE_FORMAT(c_Date,'%Y-%m') AS dt FROM tbl_complaintsheet  WHERE dt LIKE '2014%' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c_Date, '%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(cd_Id), DATE_FORMAT(cd_Date,'%Y-%m') AS cd FROM  tbl_complaintsheet WHERE YEAR(cd_date) = 2014;
```